# Google Drive Android API 'queryChildren' vs. filter

Tags: google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I wonder if there is a difference between using the following filter construct:

```
  GoogleApiClient GAC;
  ...
  ArrayList<Filter> fltrs = new ArrayList<Filter>();
  fltrs.add(Filters.in(SearchableField.PARENTS, (DriveId)id));
  ...
  Query qry = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.and(fltrs)).build();
  MetadataBufferResult rslt = Drive.DriveApi.query(GAC, query).await();
```

as opposed to

```
  DriveFolder dFld = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(GAC, (DriveId)id)
  dFld.queryChildren(GAC, qry).await():
```

The 'queryChildren' seems redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are functionally equivalent.